# Checking if form.date_select from form exists in PostgreSQL data field. Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, forms, date

I have a form with date_select.

```
<%= form_for @post, url: { controller: "posts", action: "create" } do |form| %>
<%= form.date_select :date %>
```

[image]

---

I'm trying to check in my **post_controller.rb** if Post exists based on post.date and post.user_id fields with the line below

```
@existing_post = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id, date: params[:post][:date].to_s).first


if @existing_post.present?
  @existing_post.body += "<hr>#{params[:post][:body]}"
  @existing_post.save(post_params)
else
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
end
```

---

If post exists, I want to append using += if post doesn't exist, I want to create new.But the `params[:post][:date].to_s` doesn't return any data. It looks **NIL**. What am I missing?

**Post Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 AND "posts"."date" IS NULL ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok Solved.

Apparently I was supposed to format the date.

```
# date(1i)"=>"2021", "date(2i)"=>"3", "date(3i)"=>"22"
@selected_date = Date.new(params["post"]["date(1i)"].to_i,
                          params["post"]["date(2i)"].to_i,
                          params["post"]["date(3i)"].to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails built in multiparameter assignment by assigning the parameter to a model instance:

```
date = Post.new(params.fetch(:post).permit(:date)).date

@existing_post = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id, date: date).first

if @existing_post.present?
  # you should probally use strftime instead of implicit casting
  @existing_post.body += "<hr>#{date.to_s}" 
  @existing_post.save(post_params)
else
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
end
```